# VS2012 Open file in existing window from Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am using VS2012 community, to edit scripts in unity. To get project sync and code completion, I have to hit "Sync monodevelope project" button in unity. This open the unity project scripts in VS2012 with all the bells and whistle like unity code completion.

But when I double click a script in unity, it opens up a brand new instance of VS2012 without all the bells and whistles. How I can force it to open that existing file in the currently opened instance of VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-importing the entire project. This solved it for me.